# How to hide items?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am working on a project in which we load two almost identical models. I have a function that paints the different dbId elements of the models in different colors. Next, I have to hide those elements that are the same for the two models. I tried many options, but did not succeed. I ask for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `visibiliyManager` (see unofficial doc [here](https://autodesk-forge.gitee.io/helpcenter/classes/autodesk.viewing.private.visibilitymanager.html)):

```
modelA.visibilityManager.hide(dbidsA) //single or array
modelB.visibilityManager.hide(dbidsB)
```

Comment: I'm use this code viewerApp.impl.modelQueue().findModel(1).visibilityManager.hide(). Why does the method work incorrectly?

Comment: Not sure how you managed to get it wrong but here's a working [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/myfdpkzc/)